# Run Task Schedule with Least Privileged User

Tags: permissions, windows-server-2012, scheduled-tasks

I need to run the EAServer application (exe/ bat file) from Task Schedule BUT with the local user who has least the privilege permissions.

Your kind support would be highly appreciated.

Thanks
Malik Adeel Imtiaz

Comment: Do you want to perform a task on behalf of an account which does not have permission to do so? or do you want to perform this task when the specified user logs on, regardless of which account to run the service on?

Comment: Dear Akina, thanks for your reply. i want to run the TASK SCHEDULE from local created user without giving that user ADMINISTRATOR rights / permission.

Comment: Local user may start task scheduler and create its own tasks relative to his events (log in, for example) behalf of his account. But he must have enough privileges to execute the actions performed in task action. If the user have no such privileges, you may add them to his account (via gpedit, for example), or use another account for task execution.